# Can I mount an ext3 filesystem on linux so files on the mount are owned by a userid?

Tags: mount, ext3

I'd like to mount an ext3 filesystem via /etc/fstab so that the files in the mount are owned by a particular user. Is this possible ? 
I've looked at `man mount` but couldn't find an option to do this. ( Similar to setting uid and gid for a vfat mount ).

Is there any option besides doing running chown on the whole mounted filesystem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible to do in fstab or mount with ext3 because the ownership info is stored within the file system, as opposed to being a property of the file system. Run chown -R.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in an answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/mounting-an-ext3-fs-with-user-privledges), [`bindfs`](http://bindfs.org/) can be used to create a remapped mounting of a directory or filesystem with modified userid.  This seems to work acceptably for me.  I just did `sudo bindfs -u myusername fs-mountpoint new-mountpoint` and it happened.  I'm not sure how well this will work in `fstab`, though, since `bindfs` is a FUSE filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a patch around for mounting ext2/3 with a fixed uid for all files, I couldn't figure out if it has made it into the kernel yet, but if it has it's in 2.6.31+ .

The option is anyway uid=userid, as in e.g. mount -o uid=500 /dev/sda1 /mnt/mydisk

It'll certainly be handy if you have removable drives formatted as ext3, moving it back& forth between machines where your have a different user id.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I wanted this for the same reason you mentioned.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work—I get a vague error message that lists, among other possible causes, bad mount option; the `uid=` option is not documented for ext* file systems.